# Tailwind CSS logo centered

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/w5c36epd/

If you look closely you can see that the logo is not actually centered. I have tried different flexbox options such as:

```
<div class="flex-shrink-0 justify-center">
    <img class="h-64 w-64" src="../../assets/images/logo.svg" alt="Workflow logo">
</div>
```

but I can't seem to align it.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of how you'd like to center it. To me it looks centered.

Answer (score 2):

Try these :

```
 1. Place-items : center;
 2. align-items : center;
 3. justify-content : center;
```

Comment: i am quite new to this tailwind where do i add those? :D

Comment: This is a problem with Tailwind, you have to learn a lot of syntaxes, what works for me is, put basic tailwind CSS class names, and for more critical CSS (one or two properties), just do inline CSS. to answer your question just put on inline CSS and try it out for that div, later on, you can always search the tailwind docs

Comment: Can you try and change my fiddle so i can see exactly what youm ena?

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is you need to make 3 section part using `flex basis`, `basis` has the size up-to 12 and you want to divide it by 3. left: `basis-5/12`, middle: `basis-2/12`, and right: `basis-5/12`.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7jgwcdvq/13/

Answer (score -1):

To keep the logo truly centered, you'll utilize flex-grow and flex-basis. The sides will use `flex-grow: 1;` and `flex-basis: 0px;`. This will keep the logo in the center and have the sides fill the rest of the space.

The tailwind classes are `grow` ([docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-grow)) and `basis-0` ([docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-basis))  (Tailwind v3.4.0 as of typing this)

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vkfn5ewa/10/